# Google Maps API, markers in a for loop and attributes changing

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i'm getting a problem with google markers of Maps API,

here is the code of an ajax succes function (map is an argument of the function that contain this code) :

```
success: function(data) {
   var tmpmap = map;                         //Without this the map wont let me add markers
   ris = JSON.parse(data);                   //Parsing to json
   for (var i = 0; i < ris.length - 1; i++) {//Here is the for 
      var id = ris[i].id_sede;               //Here i get the id from the json
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  //Here i create the marker
         map: tmpmap,
         mid: id,                            //And there is where i got that problem.
         position: {
         lat: parseFloat(ris[i].latitude),
         lng: parseFloat(ris[i].longitude)
      }
});
```

The data that ajax collect is a normal SQL query that contains latitude, longitude the ID and some extra info.

So the problem is that: at every cycle of the for, each marker created before assume the value of the current "mid" (map ID).

TL;DR i have 4 markers that had as mid 1 2 3 and 4 at the end of the cycle all the marker will have 4 as a value of mid instead of 1 2 3 and 4.

And the final question is: how can i prevent this behaviour? Am i creating markers properly? And why when i change the value of a markers all other markers do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Glossary/IIFE), so that each maker gets it's own data:

```
success: function (data) {
  var tmpmap = map; //Without this the map wont let me add markers
  ris = JSON.parse(data); //Parsing to json
  for (var i = 0; i < ris.length - 1; i++) { //Here is the for 
    // IIFE
    (function (entry) {
      // remember original element as variable entry
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ //Here i create the marker
        map: tmpmap,
        mid: entry.id_sede, // still the original ID
        position: {
          lat: parseFloat(entry.latitude),
          lng: parseFloat(entry.longitude)
        }
      });
    }) (ris[i]); // pass original element into IIFEE
  }
});
```

Because without an IIFE until the first marker gets its' ID the variable `i` might have already reached the condition `ris.length - 1`. So in this case the variable `id` won't contain the ID of the first marker.

By using a IIFE you can use the original entry-element out of `ris`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot!

Comment: if it helped you solve all issues, please, mark it as right answer, thank you.